# Confused by the notation: conditional probability and parameters

Tags: probability, statistics, notation, conditional-probability

When studying the mathematical statistics, I notice that there is some confusion between the notations of conditional probability and giving parameters to the probability function.

I am confused quite often when seeing these two notations are used interchangeably. For example, I understand easily that $f(x|y)$ is a conditional probability, but I am not quite confident when seeing something like $f(x|\theta)$ that $\theta$ plays a role of being parameter instead of actual conditional probability.

Is there a way to clearly tell the difference between these two notations? How can I ensure the correct notation being used in the question?

Comment: Usually context should make it unambiguous.

Comment: $f(x\mid\theta)$ is a "conditional probability" (well, it is the pdf).  For example, if $\theta$ takes value in a finite discrete set $\Theta$ (say you put the uniform distribution on it) and for each $\theta$ you define your model $M_\theta$, then $f(x\mid\theta)$ really is the conditional pdf.

Comment: In Bayesian statistics there is essentially no difference. If you allow improper priors then they really are the same thing.